# No such partition grub rescue

Tags: grub

I purchased Dell Inspiron Mini 1011 Netbook with Windows 7 pre installed. I installed Ubuntu 10.10 version and it loaded perfectly well.

My Wi-fi was not connected. Hence I decided to delete Ubuntu.

When I boot now, I get the error:

```
#22: "no such partition".
```

Reinstalling Windows is not an option, because Dell has not supplied the Windows 7 starter pack.

Answer (score 2):

The recovery partition is generally a seperate partition, and has to have a bootloader aware of it - installing linux often removes that bootloader, even if the partition is there. there IS, however a slightly roundabout way to get windows usable again - you will need a system rescue disk - [which you can generate from another windows 7 system](http://www.shivaranjan.com/2009/05/20/windows-7-how-to-create-a-system-repair-rescue-recovery-disc/). that SHOULD restore the original bootloader.

You should then be able to make recovery disks from your windows install.